# Remove section with swipe sectionList

Tags: react-native, react-native-sectionlist

I'm new to react-native
I want to have a section list with swipe to remove functionality. 
I found this library : react-native-swipeout 
which works well with FlatList , 
I managed to add the swiping only to the section header but I want to swipe the entire section together as one unit.

Adding Image of current situation

[image]

the grey background is the section header and the white is the array of data
code snippet

```
renderSectionHeader = ({section, index}) => {

    const swipeSettings = {
        autoClose: true,
        onColse: (secId, rowId, direction) => {

        },
        onOpen: (secId, rowId, direction) => {

        },
        right: [
            {
                onPress: () => {
                },
                text: 'Remove', type: 'delete'
            }
        ],
        rowId: 1,
        sectionId: index,
        //  set active swipeout item
        _handleSwipeout: (sectionID, rowID) => {
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                rows[i].active = i == rowID;
            }
            this._updateDataSource(rows)
        },
    };

    return (

        <Swipeout
            {...swipeSettings}
        >
            <View style={{justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                <Text>{section.itemName}</Text>
                <Text>${section.itemTotalPrice}</Text>
            </View>
         </Swipeout>

    )
};
```